# I cannot include config.h in gimp

Tags: c, gimp

I am new to gimp programming. I have installed the gimp and using it in Visual Studio 2010. The configuration is ok.

I was trying to compile the code from here:
 http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/blur.c

The problem is that when including `config.h`, I am getting this:

> fatal error C1189: #error : "config.h must be included prior to stdplugins-intl.h"

where is this `config.h` file located?

Also, I have problem with this code:

`GimpRunMode run_mode; run_mode = param[0].data.d_int32;`

it says a value of type `gint32` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `GimpRunMode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.h is generated when you run ./configure in the root of the gimp directory. If you have run configure it should have ended up in the root of the gimp directory.

As to your other problem, try casting the value before assigning it:

```
GimpRunMode run_mode;
run_mode = (GimpRunMode)param[0].data.d_int32;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt reply. the 2nd problem is fixed. but how to run the ./configure in the root of gimp directory?

Comment: Since you're talking about Visual Studio, I'm guessing you're running Windows. The configure script is a bash shell script and the easiest way to run in Windows would be to install Cygwin, that will give you access to bash and the other necessary tools.